# Cmake link issue: undefined reference to Button::mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent*)

Tags: c++, qt, cmake

I am trying to compile a group Qt project with cmake. It worked until I added the GUI part.
main.cpp:

```
#include <QtWidgets> 

int start_GUI(int argc, char *argv[]){
    QApplication a(argc, argv); 
    Window * window = new Window();
    SSConnection *ssc = new SSConnection();
    Window window;
    return a;
}
```

cmake:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)   
project(client)              
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)          
set(SOURCE_FILES  main.cpp)

find_package(Qt5Widgets REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt5WebSockets REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt5Gui REQUIRED)

set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)

add_executable(client_main ${SOURCE_FILES}) 

qt5_use_modules(client_main Widgets Gui WebSockets)
```

output:

```
undefined reference to `Button::mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent*)'
undefined reference to `non-virtual thunk to Button::mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent*)'
```

The Button class is just a QObject to add a button to the screen
Button:

```
class Button : public QObject , public QGraphicsRectItem
{
Q_OBJECT
public:
    Button(QString name, QGraphicsItem * parent = NULL);
    void mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent * event);

signals:
    void clicked();
private:
    QGraphicsTextItem * text;
    QPushButton * button;
    QGraphicsRectItem * rect;
};
```

Any suggestions on how to fix the linking error

Comment: what is `Button`?, please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Have you tried running this with qmake?
Have you treid cleaning it and rebuilding?

Comment: It is a project created in QtCreator and thus does run with qmake.

Answer (score 0):

To solve the linker error, implement this method or remove it.

`void mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent * event);`